# Single form multiple submit

Tags: forms, webforms

I have one simple quick contact form ([webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)), it's working fine but sometimes when user fill form n submit it get submitted 2 times or 3 times.

I have checked the submission table that same data is submitted on same time 2 or 3 times.

This happens sometime but not for all submit .

If anybody have resolved this type of issue then please let me know how you have resolved it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can try out a more general solution for all the forms by using [Hide Submit Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit)

> Some users accidentally click the submit button more than once while
>   waiting for their post to be saved. In some cases this may result
>   duplicate postings or duplicate e-commerce orders.
>
> There are few ideas on how to solve duplicate postings but none is
>   perfect. One of the solutions is a bit of jQuery to hide or disable
>   the submit button after it has been clicked and replace it with an
>   informative text such as "Processing..." .
>
> This module wraps that jQuery code and provides some options. Of
>   course this, too, is not a perfect solution as it requires Javascript
>   to be enabled. For browsers with Javascript disabled this module will
>   have no effect at all.

Comment: This module is so cool, first time to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you restricted the per user submission like below image.

[image]

Path for this perticular configuration is `node/%/webform/configure`.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent duplicate submissions for all webforms in /admin/structure/webform/config

[image]

It prevents someone from clicking submit twice and posting the exact same data.

If a user clicks submit and then back and submit again, you will get duplicate submissions.

If the user clicks submit twice (very fast) you will not get a duplicate submission.